# blockchain.info API: Payments not forwarded to main wallet

Tags: bitcoin

Trying to get some help here as we haven't been successful with the Customer Support on blockchain.info (yet) and this matter is somewhat revenue impacting.

We use blockchain.info on our site to receive and send bitcoin. This has worked great for us with no issues; however this morning we noticed transactions we received have not been forwarded to our main wallet, thus not triggering the callback URL, thus causing customers to complain because they sent us payment - but we didn't show that we received the payment!

A few examples below:
https://blockchain.info/tx/bad177cec74f748b60ee5b1eb49e2bd7811aa1e31e084f61920ad79e234a294c

https://blockchain.info/tx/616a76c9aff3bd656609e6501dd0581f7703f39eb6479049d1154c86ef959360

https://blockchain.info/tx/07e76d952b1538eae97d535bae728a2a1ad212f235406b790d8f3dd262021e69

If anyone can help with this, we'd gladly send some bitcoin your way for the trouble!

Comment: do you get a "403 error" ?

Comment: We have the same problem, notifications are not sent to our server anymore since yesterday.

Comment: Blockchain's API has numerous problems - BTC not being forwarded, callbacks not being sent, generated addresses not showing up in the account... can't get anything but late, generic denial responses from their team. They seem to be overwhelmed and struggling.

Answer (score -1):

blockchain.info is not support it any more

try this https://apirone.com/docs/forwardingv1/

Answer (score -3):

Seems like you are reusing addresses after long time.

They stop monitoring address for which the first TX in has 6 confirmations. All TX within that time are processed.

This is known, and intentional feature from BlockChain.info.

btw, BTC: 1GpiMf47sXsbaGCW7q266RG8T4fUDoTC1o

:)

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue, our main wallet has < 500 transactions total. Blockchain mentions the wallet can support 5k transactions

Comment: No! I mean the forwarding address.

Comment: Well that's not correct, we are using pretty old forwarding addresses where the first TX has thousands of confirmations. It is still being monitored and the forwarding still works. At least please provide a source for what you are saying because it is either wrong, or you misunderstood what you've read.

Comment: Maybe. I had a similar problem once, and this was the result. I got my BTC by contacting the operator on BTCTalk.